# Ajax Layered Navigation module?

Tags: magento2, layered-navigation, ajax

Does anyone know a simple Magento 2 module which enables Ajax in the layered navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Extension:

Ajax Layered Navigation module for Magento2 [here](https://github.com/czone-tech/magento2-ajaxified-catalog)

Answer (score 0):

> Note : I am suggesting an extension because OP asked for the same

Till now I have used this extension and works like charm for me,

I have used this extension in my couple of projects so I can say it works fine.

https://github.com/NikZh/magento2-multiple-layered-navigation